# Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with image

Tags: vb.net, image, parameters, dbnull

I'm using a SQL Server 2008 stored procedure to create a new record with 
this syntax:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@photo", DBNull.Value)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

but the result is a:

```
Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with image
```

Photo is not the only parameter but is the only image one, I am not passing 
a nvarchar but a null value, am I missing something?

Answer (score 14):

If you pass in `DBNull.Value` as the value, ADO.NET can't figure out what type the parameter should be. If you specify a string, or an integer value, the type of the SQL parameter can be derived from the value provided - but what type should `DBNull.Value` be turned into??

When passing in a NULL value, you need to specify that `SqlDbType` yourself, explicitly:

```
Dim photoParam As New SqlParameter("@photo", SqlDbType.Image)
photoParam.Value = DBNull.Value
cmd.Parameters.Add(photoParam)

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

That should work, I hope!

**Update:** same thing in C# would be:

```
SqlParameter photoParam = new SqlParameter("@photo", SqlDbType.Image);
photoParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add(photoParam);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

There's a great, free, very useful [VB.NET-to-C# converter out there](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/) - use it!

Comment: c# could also be written in 1 line: `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("photo", SqlDbType.Image) { Value = DBNull.Value });`

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim photo_NULL As New SqlTypes.SqlBytes
.Pararameters.AddWithValue("@photo", IIf(IsNothing(Photo), photo_NULL, Photo))
.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
F_return = (.ExecuteNonQuery > 0)
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!