# Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with image for Null Image

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have the following code: I am getting the following error message:

```
Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with image
```

when the code tries to do:  `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` Note that I get this error only when `_ImageB` is `null`. `ImageB` is stored as a Image Data type in the SQL Server table.

```
if (_ImageB == null)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageB", DBNull.Value);
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageB", _ImageB);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420708/operand-type-clash-nvarchar-is-incompatible-with-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this!

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ImageB", SqlDbType.Image).Value = _ImageB == null ? DBNull.Value : _ImageB;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var imageParameter = new SqlParameter("@Column", SqlDbType.Image) { Value = DBNull.Value};

command.Parameters.Add(imageParameter);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**